# Is it possible to trigger a GitHub action to a different repository?

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions

If I have a public repo which has a workflow setup to be triggered when something is pushed to master, can I then trigger another workflow from a different repo to trigger?

The reason I want to do this is because my public repo is used to allow anyone to contribute but I want to make another repo which is private that handles the build process/deployment that can't be seen. Is there a better way to handle this kind of use case with GitHub actions? - I basically don't want my build process on my server to be public.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From doing more research I found this marketplace plug-in which solves what I want and calls another repository which triggers another build which is a private repository, you can enter a name of your choice and have a front facing repo which is public and keep all your CI/CD stuff in a private repo:

<s>https://github.com/marketplace/actions/dispatch-action</s> (Deprecated, use https://github.com/marketplace/actions/repository-dispatch instead)

Comment: Kindly add context to any links so your answer is self contained, meaning the answer needs to be here in the Answer itself. See ["Provide context for links"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). It would be preferable if you could answer the Question here and link only as a reference. See [When to flag an answer as “not an answer”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer). Alternatively add the link in a comment on your Question.

Answer (score 3):

```
name: Trigger automation tests
steps:
- uses: actions/github-script@v6
  with:
    github-token: ${{ secrets.PERSONAL_TOKEN }}
    script: |
      await github.rest.actions.createWorkflowDispatch({
       owner: '*****',
       repo: '*****',
       workflow_id: '*****.yml',
       ref: 'main'
      })
```

1. Create personal access token in target repository.
2. Add this personal access token as secret in both repositories.
3. Create a new
   workflow or edit one which is already exists (yml file).
4. Add the above step
   to yml file.

owner = organization / personal gitHub.

repo = target repository to run.

workflow_id = yml file name of the target workflow.

ref = which brench to run in target repository